# jQuery ajax cross domain call

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I have the following code to make a jsonp call.

```
  var contacts;
     $.ajax({
                            url: "http://localhost:51973/Service1/GetContacts",
                            type: "GET",
                            async: false,
                            data: { companyName: company },
                            dataType: "jsonp",
                            success: function(data) {
                                contacts = data;
                            },
                            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                alert("error " + XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
                            }
                        });
```

but for whatever reason I get the contacts as undefined. I inspected the traffic using fiddler and I found the it was getting the following response.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Mon, 09 Apr 2012 14:52:33 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Content-Length: 100
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Connection: Close

jQuery17107471185381512466_1333983153278([{"Email":"john@test.com","Name":"Test Company"}]);
```

so why is contacts variable not being set properly?

Comment: Is "data" received in success all right?
If so, are you sure you're not reading it before the ajax call? From what I see you're trying to make it synchronous, but is it working?

Comment: Personally, I'd quickly `alert(data)` before assigning it to `contacts` just to see if you actually get that value.

Comment: or console.log it since you can inspect it as an object without halting the progress of the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess that you are trying to use the contacts variable right after the ajax call.  You cannot do that.  The ajax call is asychronous and thus completes sometime AFTER the ajax call completes.  When it completes, the success handler is called.  You need to put any code or any function calls that actually use the contacts information inside the success handler.  This is asynchronous programming and you have to code it differently.

```
success: function(data) {
    contacts = data;
    // put your code or function calls here that use the contacts data
},
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. So setting async: false doesn't have any effect on the call?

Comment: First off, synchronous ajax calls are bad.  They lock up the browser during the call.  Second off, JSONP calls cannot be synchronous (because of the way they work) so the `async: false` setting has no effect for JSONP calls.